# Is $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{11} + 10^\frac{1}{3}]$ equal to $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{11}, 10^\frac{1}{3}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

> Is $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{11} + 10^\frac{1}{3}]$ equal to $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{11}, 10^\frac{1}{3}]$?

It is clear that $\sqrt{11} + 10^\frac{1}{3} \in \mathbb Q[\sqrt{11}, 10^\frac{1}{3}]$ and that $\mathbb Q \subset \mathbb Q[\sqrt{11}, 10^\frac{1}{3}]$. Thus $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{11} + 10^\frac{1}{3}] \subset \mathbb Q[\sqrt{11}, 10^\frac{1}{3}]$.

Can we somehow prove that either $\sqrt{11}$ or $10^\frac{1}{3} \in \mathbb Q[\sqrt{11} + 10^\frac{1}{3}]$ and demonstrate that $\mathbb Q[\sqrt{11}, 10^\frac{1}{3}] \subset \mathbb Q[\sqrt{11} + 10^\frac{1}{3}]$.

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, I guess i better delete my comment. Thanks. :)

Comment: As an upper bound we have $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11}, 10^{1/3}):\mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11}, 10^{1/3}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11}):\mathbb{Q}] \leq 3 \times 2 = 6$. But the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{11} + 10^{1/3}$ is ([Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt(11)+%2B+10%5E(1%2F3)+minimal+polynomial)) $= x^6 - 33x^4 - 20x^3 + 363x^2 - 660x - 1231$, so it has degree $6$. So they must have the same degree and are thus the same field.

Comment: A possible approach that just came to mind: use the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11}, 10^{1/3}, e^{2 \pi i/3})$ to find all the intermediate fields, and then observe that $\sqrt{11} + 10^{1/3}$ is only in the intermediate fields containing $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{11}, 10^{1/3})$.  Though it's probably less constructive, and at the same time more computationally intensive, than the accepted answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\newcommand{\al}{\alpha}\al=\sqrt{11}+10^{1/3}$. Then
$$(\al-\sqrt{11})^3=10.$$
So
$$\al^3+33\al-10=(3\al^2+11)\sqrt{11}$$
and then $\sqrt{11}\in\Bbb Q(\al)$.

Comment: Extremely neat and elegant. I hope I can use the technique in the future.